# OpenPGP library

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard, openpgp

Is there a library to create OpenPGP keys, or to encrypt a file using OpenPGP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [GPGMe](http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html).  See the [manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/) entries on [generating keys](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Generating-Keys.html#Generating-Keys) and [encrypting a plain-text](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Encrypting-a-Plaintext.html#Encrypting-a-Plaintext).

There are [Objective-C bindings](http://macgpg.sourceforge.net/docs/GPGME-documentation/IntroGPGME.html), but you could also just use it directly.

Comment: GPGMe is GPL3, I think this is not compatible with AppStore policy.

Comment: @Marcin, the question said nothing about the Mac App Store.  Distributing Mac apps directly is still possible.

Comment: @Marcin, and it seems to be under LGPLv2.1 not GPLv3.  See http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/ .  It says, "The GNU Lesser General Public License says how you can copy and share `GnuPG Made Easy'." (GPGME) and links to http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Library-Copying.html#Library-Copying

Comment: sure, this is just notification that it may be problematic with AppStore. Isn't it that any GPL is disallowed ? I think so.

Answer (score 2):

There is another project: [ObjectivePGP](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP) for iOS and OSX